# Abrir la ventanta de un chat de Telegram

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy intentando abrir un chat especifico de telegram desde mi app.

```kotlin
    private fun openTelegramApp(numberPhone: String, msg: String) {
        try {
            val packageManager: PackageManager = packageManager
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            val url = "http://t.me/" + numberPhone
            intent.setPackage("org.telegram.messenger")
            intent.data = Uri.parse(url)
            if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                startActivity(intent)
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "openWhatsApp: No Telegram installed")
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("ERROR TELEGRAM", e.toString())

        }

    }
```

### He probado:

- Pasar el número de teléfono (sin exito)
- Obtener el idContacto de Telegram que se guarda en contactos en el dipositivo (sin exito)

Alguien sabe como se puede armar un Intent para que se pueda abrir concretamente a un chat especifico?

### Investigación:

He visto que la app Contactos de google al ir al detalle de contacto, se muestra una lista de los servicios disponibles para Telegram: realizar directamente videollamada, mensaje, llamada etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método de la url sólo funciona con nombres de usuario, no con números. Si lo quieres como en la app de contactos, puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
enum class TelegramAction { MESSAGE, VOICE_CALL, VIDEO_CALL }

private fun openTelegramApp(action: TelegramAction, phoneNumber: String) {
    val uri = getTelegramUri(action, phoneNumber)
    if (uri == null) {
        // telegram no está instalado o el número no pertence a ningún contacto
    } else {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}

private fun getTelegramUri(telegramAction: TelegramAction, phoneNumber: String): Uri? {
    val prefix = "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.org.telegram.messenger.android."
    val action = when (telegramAction) {
        TelegramAction.MESSAGE -> "profile"
        TelegramAction.VOICE_CALL -> "call"
        TelegramAction.VIDEO_CALL -> "call.video"
    }
    val mimeType = prefix + action
    val filter = "${ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE} = '$mimeType' AND " +
            "${ContactsContract.Data.DATA3} LIKE '%$phoneNumber'"
    return contentResolver.query(
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
        arrayOf(ContactsContract.Data._ID),
        filter, null, null, null
    )?.use { cursor ->
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            "${ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI}/${cursor.getString(0)}".toUri()
        else null
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me ha funcionado

Answer (score 2):

Puedes abrir un grupo o iniciar un chat con un usuario

**Abrir grupo en Telegram**

mediante un Intent usando la url del grupo y el package name de Telegram:

```
  val urlGroup = "https://t.me/<nombre grupo>"
  val openTelegram = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlGroup))
   openTelegram.setPackage("org.telegram.messenger")
   startActivity(openTelegram)
```

Si deseas abrir un chat con un usuario especifico:

**Abrir chat con usuario en Telegram**

mediante un Intent usando la url del grupo y el package name de Telegram:

```
  val urlUser = "https://t.me/<usuario>"
  val openTelegram = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlUser))
   openTelegram.setPackage("org.telegram.messenger")
   startActivity(openTelegram)
```

Comment: Interesante, me ha dado una idea extra para implementar